# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c'

Tags: oracle, xampp, oracle9i, oci8, php-8

I'm trying to enable `oci8_12c` extension with `Instant client 12.2` in PHP 8.0.7. on windows x64

1. I've uncommented `extension=oci8_12c` in my php.ini file.
2. Downloaded and placed `php_oci8-3.0.1-8.0-ts-vs16-x64` files in my `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder
3. Downloaded `instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip` file and extracted to `C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_2` also added to PATH.
4. Downloaded & installed `vcredist_x64.exe` from [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-visual-c-2013-redistributable-package-d8ccd6a5-4e26-c290-517b-8da6cfdf4f10)
5. Restarted my PC.

But still when I run `php --ini` in my cmd. I get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: 
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

[phpinfo() screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjM7L.png)

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days of trying and failing
I found this [article](https://odan.github.io/2017/03/21/xampp-oracle-driver-setup-v12.html) by Daniel Opitz.

The step I was missing in my question post was

`Copy all *.dll files: to c:\xampp\php`

`Copy all *.dll files to c:\xampp\apache\bin (We need a second copy here for apache)`

Thats it !! After adding the .dll files to my root php and apache, the warning was resolved.