# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_19' windows 11 (php8.1.20) tried most of the available solutions but nothing is working

Tags: php, windows, oci8

**tried most of the available solutions but nothing is working !!!!**

I have downloaded a fresh php from [here](https://windows.php.net/download/) which is `php-8.1.20-nts-Win32-vs16-x64.zip` in Windows 11 64-bit PC. This is working properly for all default libraries whenever I update the ini file to enable any extension it shows this warning. All other libraries have no issue. Whenever I enable any extension manually this warning arises.

[image]

I have tried most of the available solutions but nothing is working. But I have tried the same thing in Windows 10 64-bit PC which is working perfectly. Is there any OS architecture dependency? Haven't found much about it.

Here is my phpinfo()

[image]

Comment: Define 'tried most of the available solutions but nothing is working.'

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Instant Client is needed. Download it from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html and extract it into your working directory.

Comment: I don't think it's only related to oracle, any extension I'm enabling manually it's showing the same warning

Comment: But you wrote it different: `All other libraries have no issue`. The answer is correct, this extension library needs the corresponding client library, just like mysql does..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe same issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162636/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-oci8-12c?rq=1). Check that your ext directory contains all the needed dlls if not install them. The shown path is relative did you configure the `extension_dir` in `php.ini` ? I recommend to use an absolute path to avoid issues with working directory not being the right one.

Comment: Tried already no luck